# putting Close(); in Form_FormClosing delays exit by 3-4 seconds

Tags: c#, .net

So in my program, sometimes a .net form will hide but not close, leaving it running in the background. Is there a way to make sure everything is closed?

Code:

```
    private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `Close()` do? Why does `Close()` take 3-4 seconds to execute?

Comment: Close(); is the default close method for a .net form.

Comment: Iterate over https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=net-5.0 and call `Close` on each of them. If it is still slow in closing, use the debugger to work out _where_ it is slow.

Answer (score 2):

The form is already closing, there is no need to call `Close()` again from the `FormClosing` event handler.  Remove it.

By placing `Close` in the `FormClosing` event handler you are probably causing *infinite recursion* and/or *flooding of the message pump*.  The application is most likely crashing.

If your app isn't being responsive to closure, ensure you aren't running any [foreground threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/foreground-and-background-threads) that could be preventing your app from exiting.  See [`Thread.IsBackground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground?view=net-5.0) for more information.

Comment: I'm not running any threads in my application.